# How do I achieve a texture like this using CSS3 gradients?

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

How do I achieve a texture like this using CSS3 gradients?

[image: this]

[image: and this]

Comment: First one is easy, but the 2nd one... Anyway, don't recommend to use CSS to draw complex patterns. Last, they are **not** gradients.

Answer (score 2):

The first background is easy using [`repeating-linear-gradient`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#repeating-gradients):

```css
body {
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(
    to bottom, 
    #58D68D 0, 
    #58D68D 30px, 
    #2ECC71 30px, 
    #2ECC71 60px
  );
}
```

The second background is much more complicated and should not be a CSS solution. I recommend to use a `background-image` instead!

**It is not impossible to solve it with CSS (using `perspective`):**

```css
body {
  transform: perspective(100em) rotateX(50deg) scale(2);
  overflow:hidden;
}
div {
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(
    to bottom, 
    rgba(46, 204, 113, 0.5) 0, 
    rgba(46, 204, 113, 0.5) 30px, 
    rgba(88, 214, 141, 0.5) 30px, 
    rgba(88, 214, 141, 0.5) 60px
  ), repeating-linear-gradient(
    to right, 
    rgba(46, 204, 113, 0.5) 0, 
    rgba(46, 204, 113, 0.5) 30px, 
    rgba(88, 214, 141, 0.5) 30px, 
    rgba(88, 214, 141, 0.5) 60px
  );
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Sebastian